# How to apply a transition effect to some text when hovering over an icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I am designing a webpage and have got the icons and text how I like (no assets yet).

I have it setup so when I hover over an icon, it will change the main text to a different phrase, but it does it suddenly, I was wondering if I could setup a transition effect for the main text because I can't figure out how to do it with CSS that doesn't interfere with what I have.

Here is my code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/67m5atwg/

Basically, when the text changes from TBD to Icon1 (when you hover over the image), I would like that text to fade over instead of being sudden!

Could this be done with my existing JavaScript code?

```
function setTextIcon1(){
    document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML = "Icon1";

}
function setTextIcon2(){
    document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML = "Icon2";

}
function setTextIcon3(){
    document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML = "Icon3";

}
function setTextDefault(){
    document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML = "TBD";
}
```

Everything I tried with CSS interferes with something else. I probably have the code really convoluted, which I am sorry for as I am quite new to it all!

Thanks!

Comment: Yup it can be done using css transitions and also using JS/Jquery animate. CSS is faster if its supported by the browser. Also I'd like to suggest that you make you functions more reusable by passing the text you would like to set something like this function `setTextIcon1(text){
    document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML = text;
}`

Comment: Why the script to switch text when you could hide/show different elements instead?

Comment: @LGSon because I'm new and it took me hours just to get what I have now, so I decided to ask for help as my brain couldn't take it any longer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this instead of using script

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Medrano';
  src: url('medra.ttf');
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div.iconholder {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

img.icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.iconholder div {
  font-family: 'Medrano', sans-serif;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  order: -1;
}
.iconholder div div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.hvr-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.hvr-grow:hover,
.hvr-grow:focus,
.hvr-grow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.maintext > div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .8s;
}
.maintext .icon0 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.iconholder a:hover ~ .maintext .icon0 {
  opacity: 0;
}
#icon1:hover ~ .maintext .icon1,
#icon2:hover ~ .maintext .icon2,
#icon3:hover ~ .maintext .icon3 {  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .8s;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconholder">

  <a href="" id="icon1">
    <img class="hvr-grow" src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="Icon1" />
  </a>
  <a href="" id="icon2">
    <img class="hvr-grow" src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="Icon2" />
  </a>
  <a href="" id="icon3">
    <img class="hvr-grow" src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="Icon3" />
  </a>

  <div class="maintext">
    <div class="icon0">TBD</div>
    <div class="icon1">Icon 1</div>
    <div class="icon2">Icon 2</div>
    <div class="icon3">Icon 3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You've nailed the animation and code, but the text is bit off centre and I can't figure out how to fix it without breaking the transition, any ideas? Also when I add padding to move the text away from the icons, it goes down to the right!

Comment: @Cubly Updated my answer, it was the padding in the `iconholder` rule causing that.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out just before you replied, is there any way I can move the text up a bit away from the icons? I add padding, but it seems to make it move downwards into the icons! Thanks :)

Comment: @Cubly You can add padding to top/bottom. If you add it to left you need to compensate that when setting the `translate` value or else it becomes a little off

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JQuery:

```
function setTextIcon1(){
    $('#maintext').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).html('icon1');
        $(this).delay(300).fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

Comment: That works well, but it makes the images move upwards for a split second (when delay is 0), is there anyway to fix the images in place? Sorry for being dumb. Otherwise you nailed it!

Comment: Try to set css for #maintext - display:block; height: 115px;

Comment: Mhm, didn't seem to work. I'll try and find some information about holding items central somewhere, thanks for the jQuery code :)